# using std::condition_variable with std::timed_mutex

Tags: c++, concurrency, stl

Is it possible?  I want to use timed_mutex instead of a regular mutex with a condition_variable, but it won't compile and looking at sources

```
  void
  wait(unique_lock<mutex>& __lock, _Predicate __p)
  {
while (!__p())
  wait(__lock);
  }
```

(indentation courtesy of libc++ authors, really?)

So it looks like it is in fact limited to straight mutexes, not timed ones.  But why??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `std::conditional_variable` is limited to `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>`. However you can use the more generic [`std::condition_variable_any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable_any) with anything that has a [compatible interface](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BasicLockable).